# Tablet view for Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a site using Bootstrap 3,I have developed for desktop,
my tablet width is 768px, In bootstrap 3 i am getting tablet view for 767px. For 768px the screen is breaking completely.Is there any way to override this.

Comment: could you provide more code?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize LESS variables, in this case the `Media queries breakpoints` variables. The defaults are (you can find them [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less)):

```
@screen-xs-min: 480px
@screen-sm-min: 768px
@screen-md-min: 992px
@screen-lg-min: 1200px
```

Download the non-compiled version of Bootstrap, then customize and build it.
For more details about the building process, read [Compiling CSS and Javascript](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#compiling-css-and-javascript).